# Getting dimension data from Google analytics even when the data for that dimension is not available

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I am using the Google Analytics reporting tool in PHP.

I am having trouble when i am Querying the data when the Dimension data is not available.

For example : 
These are the dimension
ga:date,ga:countryIsoCode,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel which i have.

These are the metrics
ga:totalEvents which i have.

But the problem is that for some data ga:eventLabel is present and for some ga:eventLabel is not Present.

When i query using the dimension and metrics in the result set data does not include the data which does not have ga:eventLabel.

How can i get the data even when the ga:eventLabel is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how GA reporting works. 
Empty dimensions will almost always filter away the other dimensions. (few exceptions where GA uses (not set))
You either need to always add a value to the ga:eventLabel upstream while tracking or do the hard query work.
1. ga:eventCategory
2. ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction
3. ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
Then you - intelligently - stitch the dataset together.
You need to make sure you don't use result from 1 that is drill down in 2 etc.

Comment: Yup I got it worked. I ended up calling the API twice once for all the dimension and the metrics which I mentioned in the question. Second call to the API I removed the ga:eventLabel and added the filter for ga:eventCategory which has missing ga:eventLabel.